# Getting Zero Length String with an iterative Xquery

Tags: xml, loops, csv, xquery

Im running the following on an CSV payload via API Call to convert it into XML and trying to maintain the field names of the CSV for each row, but when testing it seems to work fine, but fails on with a  'Supplied element name is a zero-length string':

```
let $lines := tokenize(/result/text(), '\n')
let $fieldnames:=tokenize($lines[1], '\s*,\s*')
return
<results>
{
  for $line at $i in $lines
  where $i gt 1
  let $fields := tokenize($line, '\s*,\s*')
  return
  <row>{
    for $fieldname at $j in $fieldnames
    return
     element {fn:replace($fieldname,' ','_')} {fn:replace($fields[$j],'"','')}
  }</row>
}</results>
```

There are thousands of rows in the CSV, some of the values are null.

Any help would be much appreciated, xquery is not my strong suite!

Tried the above query

Comment: Reduce samples to a minimum to allow us to reproduce the problem, also make sure you format your code samples. Without minimal but complete samples of both input data and code to allow us to easily reproduce the problem we can only tell you that the error message is trying to tell you: your attempt `element {fn:replace($fieldname,' ','_')}` throws an empty string as the element name at the element constructor.

Comment: XML is not regular and trying to apply REGEX is not recommended.  You should be using an XML library and not code that is using REGEX.  REGEX is short for Regular Expressions.

Comment: "xquery is not my strong suite" - this is going to get worse and worse as AI advances - people submitting code in a language they don't understand and not having the faintest idea why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the first line of your input contains two adjacent commas, or perhaps a comma as the first or last character of the line.

But seriously, how do you expect people to debug this without seeing the input?